# Error creating UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

```
@IBAction func createAlert(sender: AnyObject) {

    if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Hey there!", message: "Are you sure?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    } else {

        if let alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

        }))
    }


        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

I keep getting errors messages. 
1) expected '{' after 'if' condition
2) Variable binding in a condition requires an initializer.
please help!!!!

Comment: Update Xcode. Yours doesn't recognize `#available(iOS 8.0, *)`.

Comment: `if let alert ...` has no block after it. Is the if even needed?

Comment: Your if let alert.addAction(... does not have an opening '{'

Comment: I'm confused... you're defining your `alert` in the first section of the if statement, but you're trying to call `addAction` on it in the else section, and then you're trying to access it from outside the if statement. Is `alert` a property you haven't told us about - and `alert` just happens to mask it?

Comment: This is the code that Xcode insisted it looked like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have quite a few syntax errors.  You don't need to wrap `alert.addAction` in an `if-let`.  Also make sure that your `if` and `else` statements line up with what you want to do.  I'm not sure what you were trying to accomplish, but I've taken a guess that you want to show a `UIAlertController` if the current device is running iOS 8 and above, an do something with devices running iOS 7 and below:

```
class VC : UIViewController {
    @IBAction func createAlert(sender: AnyObject) {

        if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Hey there!", message: "Are you sure?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))

            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            // handle iOS 7 case
            // set up a UIAlertView, etc
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You actually don't have to call dismissViewController with alert controllers. Also this code could look slightly more modern if you are using trailing closures.

Comment: thanks this worked perfectly. Im new to this, i am taking a course online and his code didnt work for my version, im guessing